# How to check for NULL in c++?

Tags: c++

Let say for example, I have a struct, and an array of the struct. What I want to do is to iterate through the array and check if any of the item is a null. I tried checking the item against NULL and (struct *) 0, that don't seem to work. Is there any reliable way to check for null value?

UPDATE Sample Code

```
struct Test{
 int a;
};

Test testArray[size];

for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
{
    if (testArray[i] == NULL) //this doesnt work
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks,

RWendi

Comment: a struct cannot be null, a pointer to a struct can.

Comment: Let's see some code where you define and initialize testArray

Comment: I would bet it is...   Test testArray[size]...

Comment: Can you please tell us *why* you want to compare with NULL?

Comment: So... the answer is... you will never have a NULL struct and you cannot compare a struct to an integer

Comment: Because not every item will be initialized.

Comment: @ed swangren you're saying just by declaring the array, it will fill it up automatically?

Comment: Ahh, I get you. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RWendi. Every item in the array WILL be correctly initialized by the default constructor.

Comment: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have an array of structs, then there are no pointers, so it doesn't make sense to check for null.

An array of n structs is literally n of those structs laid out one after the other in memory.

Could you change it to an array of pointers to structs, initialise them all to NULL, and create them as you need them?  I'd be looking into *why* you want to check for null though first - it feels like you're doing something wrong.

(Edit for code added to question)

You don't show how you define testArray, but I suspect you've done the following:

```
Test testArray[testCount];
```

If you really need to compare against null, try the following:

```
Test *testArray[testCount];
for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
{
    testArray[i] = new Test;
}
```

At this point, none of the entries will be NULL, but if later in your code you do something like:

```
testArray[3] = NULL;
```

then you'll be able to detect that with the loop you provided in your question.

Can you clarify *why* you want to compare with NULL?

(And it keeps growing again - this time to address question regarding initialisation):

As others have mentioned, comparing with NULL is not a valid way of telling if something is initialised or not.  Probably the best way forward is to write your code in such a way that you guarantee it will be initialised.

Probably the best way to do this is to put a default constructor on your Test struct (you can do this in C++, but not C).  Something like:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    A() : x(0) { }
};
```

will do the job just fine.  Now all of the structs in your array are guaranteed to exist, and be initialised with their x value set to 0.

Comment: Great answer Martin. Thanks heaps.

Comment: If by "initialized" he meant that not all members will necessarily be created (i.e. some might be null), then adding the constructor doesn't actually solve the problem. There can still be a case in which only a part of the array is initialized.

Comment: No, if you have a default constructor, and you define an array of that type, then the constructor will be called for every element of the array.  

Try it: with my example, but throw 'std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;' into the constructor too.  In your main, just say 'A a[10];'.  You'll get "ctor" printed 10 times.

Comment: A pointer can be checked on NULL only if it was initialized using std::nothtow.  'int i = new(std::nothrow) int ();' Otherwise a exception is sent and the failed initialized pointer is not set to  nullptr_t.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand; if you have an array of structs, how can any of the positions be NULL?  NULL is an integer.

Comment: NULL is not an integer. It is a representation of a pointer to nothing. Down this path leads to madness.

Comment: OK, but the point is that no element in an array of structs will ever be NULL and it is not even legal to compare a struct with NULL.

Comment: @Martin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/1331729#1331729

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether a pointer is null by comparing to 0, or by using the boolean operators like ...

```
if (ptr)
{
  //not null
}

if (!ptr)
{
  //null
}

if (ptr == 0)
{
  //null
}

if (ptr != 0)
{
  //not null
}
```

If you have an array of pointers, remember that you would need to have previously explicitly initialized any unassigned elements (pointers) to null: if you haven't initialized them, they'll contain random (non-null) values:

```
const char* array[5]; //an array of 5 pointers
array[0] = "Hello";
array[1] = "World";
//at this moment, array[2] hasn't been initialized: it's value
//is therefore unknown/undefined/random, not necessarily null.
```

Comment: A pointer can be checked on NULL only if it was initialized using std::nothtow.  'int i = new(std::nothrow) int ();' Otherwise a exception is sent and the failed initialized pointer is not set to  nullptr_t.

Comment: The normal case is that it's initialized to null by the application programmer -- `int* foo = nullptr`  -- when it's defined or maybe after it's released. Your ability to set it to null is a reason for choosing to use a pointer in the first place, otherwise you might prefer a reference.

Comment: I agree, just though that it would not hurt to make a observation about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of struct pointers, then you can check for null.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is probably setting the values to some magic number while you debug.

For example, if you run the following in Visual Studio 2008 and compile in Debug mode and set a break point at the 'return 0;' statement, 'foo' points to 0xCCCCCCCC.

```
struct Foo {
    int Bar;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Foo *foo; // foo points to 0xCCCCCCCC
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `std::vector`?

```
std::vector<Test> my_list
Test obj;

my_list.push_back(obj);
std::cout << my_list.size();
my_list[0].a = 42;

my_list.push_back(obj);
std::cout << my_list.size();
my_list[my_list.size()-1].a = 4711;
```

Answer (score 0):

For any reason if you have to test your struct objec against NULL

You can overload operator ==

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    bool operator==(const Test const * arobj)
    {
        return true;// true/false on your condition
    }
};
```

Comment: Ahhh... why?  How can you meaningfully compare NULL to a struct?

Comment: This only ensure you can use operator = on your struct, Now its user term to define condition
thats why i have said:
"For any reason if you have to test your struct objec against NULL"

Users has to define his own condition for this,